# How to filter for exists but is null in KQL

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to filter by a field that exists but is null:

sample json document

```
{
    "RawMessage": "MyLovelyTestLogWithDetails",
    "NullDetail": null,
    "EmptyDetail": "",
}
```

A exists (here rather a not exists) query like mentioned in the docs would be

```
not NullDetail:*
```

but that results in also finding all document not having that field. But i actually want to distinct not exists from exists but is explicitly set to null.

How to explicitly query only for existing field but is set to null in KQL

Comment: The KQL tag is used for Kusto Query Language